# How to create a fixed tabbar with scrollable content in vuejs?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

this is my code

```html
<template>
  <div class="">
    <Nuxt class="" />
    <NavBar class="fixed bottom-0 inset-x-0" />
  </div>
</template>
```

But i do not know what to put in the `Nuxt` div so that the text does not bleed through the tabbar.

I am trying to do this without the use of external libraries.

Here is an example of what i am trying to do
https://play.tailwindcss.com/2LsEpj3Xnf

[image]

Comment: Just looks like css only is what you need to use. Can you add a sketch of what the final solutions should look like?

Comment: I have edited the question and added a link to show what i am trying to do. Pasting the link here as well -> https://play.tailwindcss.com/2LsEpj3Xnf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a way to get the footer to the bottom with `left: 0;`, `bottom: 0;` and `position: fixed;`

```css
.content {
 overflow: auto;
 width: 100%; 
 height: calc(100vh - 80px);
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #222;
  color: green;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <div class="content">
      Contents
      <ul>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
        <li><p>Here is some content, you can scroll this area!</p></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: is there a way to make the footer not hide content? In your example, scroll down to the bottom. You will see that the TabBar is hiding content

Comment: updated my answer. you can add an inner scroll.